# How to rank multiple columns in a single row?

Tags: google-bigquery

All the rank formulas on GBQ reference page assume there are multiple rows, 1 column. 
For the below, I’m trying to figure out the rank of Algo1 through Algo5s.

theTable:

```
cid algo_1  algo_2  algo_3  algo_4  algo_5   
1     4.31    4.15    4.33    4.35    4.35
2     1.31    4.15    4.33    4.34    3.35
```

So, result is

```
cid algo_1  algo_2  algo_3  algo_4  algo_5  algo_1_rank algo_2_rank algo_3_rank algo_4_rank algo_5_rank  
1     4.31     4.15   4.33    4.35    4.35            4           5           3           1           1  
2     1.31   4.15     4.33    4.34    3.35            5           3           2           1           4
```

P.S. Actually, I was asked this question outside SO, so decided to share here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option 1 - Standard SQL

```
WITH theTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS cid, 4.31 AS algo_1, 4.15 AS algo_2, 4.33 AS algo_3, 4.35 AS algo_4, 4.35 AS algo_5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS cid, 1.31 AS algo_1, 4.15 AS algo_2, 4.33 AS algo_3, 4.35 AS algo_4, 3.35 AS algo_5
),
tempTable AS (
  SELECT 
    cid, 
    alg.k AS algo, 
    alg.v AS value, 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY v DESC) AS rnk
  FROM theTable, UNNEST(
    ARRAY[STRUCT<k STRING, v FLOAT64>("algo_1", algo_1), STRUCT("algo_2", algo_2), 
          STRUCT("algo_3", algo_3), STRUCT("algo_4", algo_4), STRUCT("algo_5", algo_5)]
  ) AS alg
)
SELECT 
  cid,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_1", value, NULL)) AS algo_1,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_2", value, NULL)) AS algo_2,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_3", value, NULL)) AS algo_3,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_4", value, NULL)) AS algo_4,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_5", value, NULL)) AS algo_5,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_1", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_1_rank,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_2", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_2_rank,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_3", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_3_rank,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_4", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_4_rank,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_5", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_5_rank
FROM tempTable
GROUP BY cid
```

> Option 2 - Legacy SQL

```
SELECT
  cid,
  MAX(IF(num = 1, value, NULL)) AS algo_1,
  MAX(IF(num = 2, value, NULL)) AS algo_2,
  MAX(IF(num = 3, value, NULL)) AS algo_3,
  MAX(IF(num = 4, value, NULL)) AS algo_4,
  MAX(IF(num = 5, value, NULL)) AS algo_5,
  MAX(IF(num = 1, rnk, NULL)) AS algo_1_rank,
  MAX(IF(num = 2, rnk, NULL)) AS algo_2_rank,
  MAX(IF(num = 3, rnk, NULL)) AS algo_3_rank,
  MAX(IF(num = 4, rnk, NULL)) AS algo_4_rank,
  MAX(IF(num = 5, rnk, NULL)) AS algo_5_rank  
FROM (
  SELECT 
    cid, num, 
    CASE 
      WHEN num = 1 THEN algo_1
      WHEN num = 2 THEN algo_2
      WHEN num = 3 THEN algo_3
      WHEN num = 4 THEN algo_4
     WHEN num = 5 THEN algo_5
    END AS value,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY value DESC) AS rnk
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT 1 AS cid, 4.31 AS algo_1, 4.15 AS algo_2, 4.33 AS algo_3, 4.35 AS algo_4, 4.35 AS algo_5),
      (SELECT 2 AS cid, 1.31 AS algo_1, 4.15 AS algo_2, 4.33 AS algo_3, 4.35 AS algo_4, 3.35 AS algo_5)
  ) AS theTable
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT INTEGER(SPLIT("1,2,3,4,5")) AS num FROM (SELECT 1)
  ) AS nums
)
GROUP BY cid
```

> Option 3 - Standard SQL with Scalar UDF

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myRank(a float64, b float64, c float64, d float64, e float64)
RETURNS ARRAY<int64>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var arr = [a, b, c, d, e];
  var sorted = arr.slice().sort(function(a,b){return b-a})
  var ranks = arr.slice().map(function(v){ return sorted.indexOf(v)+1 });
  return ranks
  """;

WITH theTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS cid, 4.31 AS algo_1, 4.15 AS algo_2, 4.33 AS algo_3, 4.35 AS algo_4, 4.35 AS algo_5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS cid, 1.31 AS algo_1, 4.15 AS algo_2, 4.33 AS algo_3, 4.35 AS algo_4, 3.35 AS algo_5
), 
tempTable AS (
  SELECT *, myRank(algo_1, algo_2, algo_3, algo_4, algo_5) AS ranks
  FROM theTable
)
SELECT 
  cid, algo_1, algo_2, algo_3, algo_4, algo_5,
  ranks[ORDINAL(1)] AS algo_1_rank, 
  ranks[ORDINAL(2)] AS algo_2_rank, 
  ranks[ORDINAL(3)] AS algo_3_rank, 
  ranks[ORDINAL(4)] AS algo_4_rank, 
  ranks[ORDINAL(5)] AS algo_5_rank
FROM tempTable
```

> Option 4 – Taking care of ranking in advance

Usually tables of schema as `theTable` is generated off of multiple rows with just one test entry per row (cid, algo, value as in `theOriginalData` below)
It makes most sense to actually do ranking right at this point

```
SELECT 
  cid,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_1", value, NULL)) AS algo_1,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_2", value, NULL)) AS algo_2,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_3", value, NULL)) AS algo_3,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_4", value, NULL)) AS algo_4,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_5", value, NULL)) AS algo_5,

  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_1", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_1_rank,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_2", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_2_rank,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_3", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_3_rank,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_4", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_4_rank,
  MAX(IF(algo = "algo_5", rnk, NULL)) AS algo_5_rank,

FROM (
  SELECT
    cid, algo, value,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY value DESC) AS rnk
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT 1 AS cid, "algo_1" AS algo, 4.31 AS value),
      (SELECT 1 AS cid, "algo_2" AS algo, 4.15 AS value),
      (SELECT 1 AS cid, "algo_3" AS algo, 4.33 AS value),
      (SELECT 1 AS cid, "algo_4" AS algo, 4.35 AS value),
      (SELECT 1 AS cid, "algo_5" AS algo, 4.35 AS value),
      (SELECT 2 AS cid, "algo_1" AS algo, 1.31 AS value),
      (SELECT 2 AS cid, "algo_2" AS algo, 4.15 AS value),
      (SELECT 2 AS cid, "algo_3" AS algo, 4.33 AS value),
      (SELECT 2 AS cid, "algo_4" AS algo, 4.34 AS value),
      (SELECT 2 AS cid, "algo_5" AS algo, 3.35 AS value)
  ) AS theOriginalData
)
GROUP BY cid
```

**Note**: if if were up to me - I would go with **Option #4** and in case if it is not possible for some reason (for example theTable already exists) I would  go with **Option #3** as it looks most elegant to me

Answer (score 1):

Mikhail gave some great solutions to your problem--please mark his response as accepted if one of them worked for you. I wanted to give an alternate form of #3 if you end up using it, though; you can express the transformation with a [SQL UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions#sql-udf-structure):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myRank(arr ARRAY<FLOAT64>) AS
((SELECT ARRAY(SELECT off + 1 FROM UNNEST(arr) x WITH OFFSET off ORDER BY x DESC)));

WITH theTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS cid, 4.31 AS algo_1, 4.15 AS algo_2, 4.33 AS algo_3, 4.35 AS algo_4, 4.35 AS algo_5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS cid, 1.31 AS algo_1, 4.15 AS algo_2, 4.33 AS algo_3, 4.35 AS algo_4, 3.35 AS algo_5
), 
tempTable AS (
  SELECT *, myRank([algo_1, algo_2, algo_3, algo_4, algo_5]) AS ranks
  FROM theTable
)
SELECT 
  cid, algo_1, algo_2, algo_3, algo_4, algo_5,
  ranks[ORDINAL(1)] AS algo_1_rank, 
  ranks[ORDINAL(2)] AS algo_2_rank, 
  ranks[ORDINAL(3)] AS algo_3_rank, 
  ranks[ORDINAL(4)] AS algo_4_rank, 
  ranks[ORDINAL(5)] AS algo_5_rank
FROM tempTable;
```

Comment: Thank you Elliott - SQL Scalar UDF is a very nice feature too. Love it!